# Error en mostrar <div> con switch y else. Método setTimeout

Tags: javascript, condiciones, setinterval, else

Me salta error de sintaxis en la línea 26, carrácter 4. Adjunto libreria.js

Quiero mostrar un tablero de ajedrez casilla a casilla `<div>` a `<div>` con un "retraso" mediante el método `setTimeout`. (También procesamos el ancho y alto de los `<div>`).

En la funcion function `function pintaConRetraso()` quiero procesar primero con un `swich` o un `if` el color del `<div>` que será blanco o negro + el ancho y alto. (en ambos casos me da error de sintaxis. Quizás no haya usado el método correcto). Dejo el if comentado.

Después con un `if` ajusto los intervalos de los `<div>` y con la función `iniciaPinta()` muestro el resultado de `pintaConRetraso()`.

Adjunto libreria.js

> function agregaAContenedor(idContenedor,textoHTML){
>   elemento(idContenedor).innerHTML+=textoHTML; }

Lo necesito en Javascript puro. Gracias de antemano.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Tablero de ajedrez</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">

        var anchoCont=document.getElementById('ancho').value;
        var altoCont=document.getElementById('alto').value;
        document.getElementById('contenedor').innerHTML='';
        document.getElementById('contenedor').style.width=anchoCont*8+"px";
        document.getElementById('contenedor').style.height=altoCont*8+"px";

  var contador=0;
  
        function pintaConRetraso(){

   for (i=0 ; i<8 ; i++){
   for (n=0 ; n<8 ; n++ ){
    if((i+n)%2==0){
                    agregaAContenedor('contendor', + '<div id="contenedor" style="background-color: white; float: left; width:'+ anchoCont +'px; height: '+ altoCont +'px"></div>');
                    i++;
            }else{
                    agregaAContenedor('contendor', + '<div id="contenedor" style="background-color: black; float: left; width:'+ anchoCont +'px; height: '+ altoCont +'px"></div>');
                    n++;
            }
                contador++;
   }
   }

            if(contador<8){
                setTimeout(pintaConRetraso,100);
            }else{
                contador=0;
                agregaAContenedor('contenedor','<br>');
                setTimeout(pintaConRetraso,100);
                }
  }
        function iniciaPinta(){
   setTimeout(pintaConRetraso,100);
  }
 
</script>
</head>
 <body>
  <h2> Crea un tablero de ajedrez estableciendo sus medidas.</h2>

  · Ancho: <input style="width: 50px;" type="text" id="ancho" value=""><br>
  · Alto:<input style="width: 50px;" type="text" id="alto" value=""><br><br>

  <input type="button" id="retraso" onClick="iniciaPinta()"value="Crear tablero con retraso">

  <div id="contenedor" style=""></div>
  


 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Estas cerrando la funcion y despues declaras un if

esto es en

break;

```
    }
}//aqui estas cerrando la funcion
```

Script corregido:

```
    var contador=0;


    function tablero(){


        /*Ajustamos el ancho y el alto del tablero*/
        var anchoCont=document.getElementById('ancho').value;
        var altoCont=document.getElementById('alto').value;
        document.getElementById('contenedor').innerHTML='';
        document.getElementById('contenedor').style.width=anchoCont*8+"px";
        document.getElementById('contenedor').style.height=altoCont*8+"px";


        function pintaConRetraso(){


        switch (num){
            i=0;
            n=0;

            //  num true = (i+n)%2==0;
            case true:
                agregaAContenedor(contendor, + '<div id="contenedor" style="background-color: white; float: left; width:'+ anchoCont +'px; height: '+ altoCont +'px"></div>');
                i++
            break;

            case false:
                agregaAContenedor(contendor, + '<div id="contenedor" style="background-color: black; float: left; width:'+ anchoCont +'px; height: '+ altoCont +'px"></div>');
                i++
            break;

            }


            /*if((i+n)%2==0){
                    agregaAContenedor(contendor, + '<div id="contenedor" style="background-color: white; float: left; width:'+ anchoCont +'px; height: '+ altoCont +'px"></div>');
                    i++;
            }else{
                    agregaAContenedor(contendor, + '<div id="contenedor" style="background-color: black; float: left; width:'+ anchoCont +'px; height: '+ altoCont +'px"></div>');
                    n++;
            }
                contador++;
            */

            if(contador<8){
                setTimeout(pintaConRetraso,100);
            }else{
                contador=0;
                agregaAContenedor('contenedor',100);
                setTimeout(pintaConRetraso,100);
                }
            }

            function iniciaPinta(){
            setTimeout(pintaConRetraso,100);
            }
```

Comment: Me sigue dando error en la línea 26, caracter 13

Comment: num true = (i+n)%2==0; esto que es, yo la comente porque no se que quieras hacer con esto .

Comment: Agrega todo tu codigo algo no tiene sentido en indicas un i++ en un switch? y a la vez todo esta en 0 ? i=0;
            n=0;

Comment: Crear una variable `num` que guarda el valor `true`. Interpreto `(i+n)%2==0` como resultado de un numero par `(0+0)/2=0`. Y estas variables aumentando en el switch, imagino que no será la forma correcta. Lo intenté con un if también, está comentado.

Comment: haz tratado de implementarlo con un for y con un if, primero no intentes dibujar nada solo ejecuta el for con el if agregas la condicion, con cosole.log('blanco'), console.log('negro') iras viendo que se va generando el patron que tu quieres ya cuando estes seguro que tu ciclo funciona entonces agregas los elementos html. Entonces para que quieres setTimeOut no le veo funcionalidad.

Comment: debes dar dos pasos atras, en una hoja dibuja un tablero de ajedrez, a cada celda escribe su posicion (renglon,columna), finalmente son dos contadores, uno para renglones otro para columnas, por tanto son dos ciclos for, en el for anidado agregas la condicion que hiciste para saber si dibuja una celda blanca o una negra, si es un tablero de ajedrez el numero de columnas es igual a numero de renglones asi que tu limite es 8, para ambos contadores. Una pequeña ayuda  if ((contadorColumnas + contadorRenglones) % 2 == 0)
       dibujaCuadro('blanco');
    else
     dibujaCuadro('negro');

Comment: Acabo de subir un nuevo código

Answer (score 0):

Hola aqui esta le puse retraso de 1000 para que se vea mejor

```js
        let retraso = 0;

        function iniciaPinta(){

            setTimeout(function(){
                let ancho = document.getElementById("ancho").value; //Obtener el ancho ingresado
                let alto = document.getElementById("alto").value; // Obtener el largo ingresado

                let tablero = [8, 8]; //Tamaño del tablero
                let anchoTablero = tablero[0] * ancho; //obtener el ancho del tablero
                let altoTablero = tablero[1] * alto; //Obtener el alto del tablero

                document.getElementById("tablero").style.width = anchoTablero + "px"; //Establecer el ancho del tablero
                document.getElementById("tablero").style.height = altoTablero + "px"; //Establecer el alto del tablero

                
                let color = 0;
                for (var i = 1; i < tablero[0]; i++) {
                    
                    PintarRetraso(color++, ancho, alto);

                    for (var k = 0; k < tablero[1]; k++) {
                        PintarRetraso(color++, ancho, alto);
                    }
                }
            }, 1);
        }

        let tablero = document.getElementById("tablero");
        function PintarRetraso(color, ancho, alto){
            
            retraso +=  1000;
            
            setTimeout(function(){
                     tablero.innerHTML += 
                    `<div style="margin-bottom: -4px;border:1px solid black;display: inline-block;background-color: ${GetColor(color)};width:${ancho}px;height:${alto}px"></div>`                   
             }, retraso);

            
            
        }

        function GetColor(i){
            return i % 2 ? "white" : "black";
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #a{
                background-color: ;
            }
        </style>
 </head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Tablero de ajedrez</title>
     <body>
        <h2> Crea un tablero de ajedrez estableciendo sus medidas.</h2>
        · Ancho: <input style="width: 50px;" type="text" id="ancho" value=""><br>
        · Alto:<input style="width: 50px;" type="text" id="alto" value=""><br><br>
        <input type="button" id="retraso" onClick="iniciaPinta()"value="Crear tablero con retraso">
        <div id="tablero" style="width: 200px">
        </div>
 </body>


</html>
```